# How to view my computer folders in ipython?

Tags: python, directory, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When I open the Ipython dashboard in my browser it opens the folder that I selected as the default local folder for ipython. However, it is not showing any of the subfolders and ipynb files that are inside that local folder.

How can I view this local folder and all of the subfolders in my Dashboard?

I have tried..

1. ipython notebook --notebook-dir=
2. creating a profile

I know there is a way since I made it work a long time ago in another computer. I just don't remember the code that I used.

I'm working in Linux Mint 17 computer. Python 2.7. I don't know what other information I should give

Comment: when you start a notebook with ipython notebook , you see all your home folders listed, what folders are you trying to access? If you want a certain directory you use `ipython notebook /your_dir`

Comment: He is using an old version of IPython that do not list folders and allow navigation. Upgrade.